# Anorm select fails with OutOfMemory on big tables

Tags: scala, anorm

executing this query fails with `OutOfMemoryError` if the table is too big:

```
import anorm._
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()
implicit val conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl)
val names: Seq[String] = SQL"select name from persons".as(SqlParser.str("name").*)
names.foreach(println)
```

how to solve it?

how can I get an `Iterator` or `Stream` (instead of a `Seq`) so that it can handle any table size?

**Update**

this code (which does not use anorm) works well on big tables:

```
val stmt = conn.createStatement()
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)  // mysql driver fails with OutOfMemory without this
val rs: ResultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select name from persons")
while (rs.next()) { 
  val name = rs.getString(1)
  println(name)
}
```

---

So, I tried with anorm as follows, but without success:

```
   val names: Seq[String] = SQL"select name from persons".withFetchSize(Some(Integer.MIN_VALUE)).as(SqlParser.str("name").*)
```

Comment: Large results should be handled with streaming: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#streaming-results

Comment: yep; I looked at that, but I don't see how to use `foreach` and a `parser` (here just a `SqlParswer.str`, but I'd like to use a `Macro.namedParser`)

Comment: What have you already tried?